# WKWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString equivalent?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

`UIWebview` has (had?) an extremely useful function that enabled access to `javascript` variables from `Swift`.

```
func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_ script: String) -> String?
```

Does `WKWebview` have an equivalent function or idiom enabling access to `javascript` variables from `Swift`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, WKWebView has the [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) method that lets you run JavaScript code and access JavaScript variables.

```swift
func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, 
  completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```